# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollLeft' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem trying to do the carousel in VueJS and Laravel. I took the code from another project as-is and installed the dependency that requires, to be more exact, the same version. at home, I make the call to the file together with another that depends but at the moment of clicking to move the carousel. It gives me the error already mentioned in the title. The function is I do not explain the error because if everything seems to be fine.

This is the code of the home carousel:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <button aria-label="Previous" type="button" class="carousel__nav carousel__nav--left" :disabled="disableLeftButton" @click="moveToClickEvent('left')">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M17.9 23.2L6.1 12 17.9.8"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <div class="carousel__items" @scroll="scrollEvent">
    <div class="card" v-for="(item, index) in data.data[rootindex].list" :key="index">

      <router-link v-if="data.data[rootindex].type === 'movie'" :to="{ name: 'show-movie', params: { id: item.id }}" class="card__link">
        <div class="card__img lazyloaded">
          <img class="lazyload" :src="'/_assets/img/covers/posters/' + item.poster" :alt="item.name">
        </div>
        <h2 class="card__name">{{item.name}}</h2>
        <div class="card__rating">
          <div class="card__stars"><div :style="{width: item.rate * 10 + '%'}"></div></div>
          <div class="card__vote">{{ item.rate }}</div>
        </div>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button aria-label="Next" type="button" class="carousel__nav carousel__nav--right" :disabled="disableRightButton" @click="moveToClickEvent('right')">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M6.1 23.2L17.9 12 6.1.8"></path>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

This is the export of the same home file:

```
<script>
  import { mapState } from "vuex";
  import carousel from '../../../packages/Carousel';
  import { debounce } from '../../../packages/Funtions';

  export default {
    name: "home",

    mixins: [carousel],

    data() {
      return {};
    },

    computed: mapState({
      data: state => state.home.data
    }),

    mounted() {
      this.$store.dispatch("GET_HOME_LIST");
      this.calculateState(this.data.length);
    },

    methods: {
      resizeEvent: debounce(function () {
        this.calculateState(this.data.length);
      }, 100),
    }
  };
</script>
```

Now I am going to show the 2 files that it is called.

resource/assets/js/users/backpages/Funtions:

```
/**
 * Debounce
 */
export const debounce = function (func, delay) {
  let timeoutID;

  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    const args = arguments;
    const that = this;

    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
      func.apply(that, args);
    }, delay);
  };
};

/**
 * Check if localStorage is supported
 */
export const supportsLocalStorage = function () {
  let supports = true;

  try {
    const test = '__vue-localStorage-check';
    window.localStorage.setItem(test, test);
    window.localStorage.removeItem(test);
  } catch (e) {
    supports = false;
  }

  return supports;
};
```

resource/assets/js/users/backpages/Carousel:

```
/**
 * Carousel
 */
import smoothscroll from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      elementWidth: 0,
      carouselWidth: 0,
      visibleWidth: 0,
      maximumPosition: 0,
      unusableVisibleWidth: 0,
      disableLeftButton: true,
      disableRightButton: false,
    };
  },

  mounted () {
    smoothscroll.polyfill();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeEvent);
  },

  beforeDestroy () {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeEvent);
  },

  methods: {
    calculateState (numberOfItems) {
      let unusableVisibleWidth = 72;
      const elementWidth = this.$refs.carouselElement.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      const carouselWidth = numberOfItems * elementWidth;
      const maximumPosition = this.$refs.carouselElement.scrollWidth;

      if (window.innerWidth >= 1200) {
        unusableVisibleWidth = 92;
      }

      const visibleWidth = this.$refs.carouselElement.offsetWidth - unusableVisibleWidth;

      this.unusableVisibleWidth = unusableVisibleWidth;
      this.elementWidth = elementWidth;
      this.carouselWidth = carouselWidth;
      this.visibleWidth = visibleWidth;
      this.maximumPosition = maximumPosition;
      this.disableLeftButton = !this.$refs.carouselElement.scrollLeft;
      this.disableRightButton = visibleWidth >= carouselWidth;
    },

    moveTo (width) {
      this.$refs.carouselElement.scrollTo({
        left: width,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    },

    moveToClickEvent (direction) {
      const invisible = this.$refs.carouselElement.scrollLeft + (direction === 'left' ? -this.visibleWidth + 1 : this.visibleWidth);
      const remainder = invisible - invisible % this.elementWidth;

      this.moveTo(remainder);
    },

    scrollEvent () {
      const scrollLeft = this.$refs.carouselElement.scrollLeft;
      const end = this.maximumPosition - this.visibleWidth - this.elementWidth;

      /* eslint-disable-next-line */
      this.disableLeftButton = 3 > scrollLeft;
      this.disableRightButton = scrollLeft > end;
    },
  },
};
```

Does anyone know why this error is? This one has me buggy since I put it on. It doesn't matter how much you look into the other project. It is as-is and works and without errors in the console.

Comment: Looks like `this.$refs.scrollCarousel` is `undefined`.  Where do you set the `ref`? I don't see it anywhere in your template

Comment: In what line did you see. `this.$refs.scrollCarousel`. I looked for it in the code and it does not appear.

Comment: Typo, I meant `this.$refs.carouselElement`

Comment: You were right I still need to define that. I defined it in the `carousel__items` div. But I keep getting errors. Thanks anyway.